# Adding a div on the condition of an option input item being selected

Tags: jquery

I have a client who wants a 'how did you find us' option on a contact form. Obviously I will do this using     select and     option but what he also wants is if the option selected is 'recommended' then a box will appear asking who recommended them. Currently I am close but this doesn't work for some reason:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-line">
<label for="findUs">How did you find us?</label> 
<select name="findUs" id="findUs">
<option>Select...</option>
<option value ="Search Engine (e.g. Google)">Search Engine (e.g. Google)</option>
<option value ="Have used us before">Have used us before</option>
<option value ="Recommendation">Recommendation</option>
<option value ="Center Parcs">Center Parcs</option>
<option value ="Yell.com">Yell.com</option>
<option value ="Free Index">Free Index</option>
<option value ="Other">Other</option>

</select>
</div>
```

**jQuery** -

```
$("#findUs").change(function() {
                var e = document.getElementById("findUs");
                var how = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                //alert(how);

                if (how == 'recommendation') {
                    $(".recommended-box").show()
                } else {
                    $(".recommended-box").hide()
                }
            });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`recommendation` != `Recommendation`. Also, if you're using jQuery, use jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/m26cg/

```
$('#findUs').change(function() {
    $(".recommended-box").toggle($(this).val() == 'Recommendation');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is `'recommendation' != 'Recommendation'`

Use [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$("#findUs").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == 'recommendation') {
        $(".recommended-box").show()
    } else {
        $(".recommended-box").hide()
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/pS2Fh/)

***OR***

```
$("#findUs").change(function () {
    $(".recommended-box").toggle($(this).val().toLowerCase() == 'recommendation');
});
```